# How does zimbra procedes with sending email to the same domain if zimbra is configured to relay the messages to a proxy server

Tags: email, smtp, zimbra

Does zimbra relay emails that are from the same domain as the expeditor or the emails are send directly to the zimbra mailbox without going trougth the relay server?

I have a mail p1@example.com and I want to send to p2@example.com, does the email from p1 pass through the relay host and than goes back to the zimbra p2 mailbox or is send directly to the p2 maibox?

To clarify my question: does zimbra do this:

1. p1 sends email ->email is relayed to the relay server->the relay server sends it back to p2

or

2. p1 sends email ->zimbra sees that is from the same domain(doesn't relay)->zimbra puts email in p2 mailbox?

Comment: Depends, what is set in `mydestination`?

Comment: mydestination of what?

Comment: Postfix's main.cf has a mydestination line, it means "what domain(s) am I responsible for accepting mail for"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is straightforward. If the zimbra (which is postfix) server is configured as the final destination for `domain.com`, while the mail is in the active queue, it will then see that it can be delivered via the local transport, and be sent directly to the mailbox, without passing through the relay server.

Comment: than local transport has a higher priority than relaying?

Comment: No, it's not a choice, if it matches relay it relays, if it matches local it goes local.